# Sharepoint site url

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, url

Okay so I want to create a site but with a different url. So normal sites would be as https://webapplication/sites/ingredients. But I want to create a site under that webapplication with a url of https://ingredients/.

Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the same web app, creating the site collection with different url can be achieved using the HNSC or Create new web app with that url.

Host Name Site collection have their own url. You can follow these steps.

- Create web application( you already did)
- Create root site collection (You already did)
- Create host named site collections
- Set alternate URLs for host named site collection

[Read this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/voyage/2014/04/27/host-named-site-collections-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Or you can create 2nd web app using the new URL.

Answer (score 3):

The near solution is to achive that is to define `managed paths` in SharePoint . where you can specify the paths in the URL namespace of a web application to use for site collections.

There are two types of managed paths that you can create:

**A wildcard inclusion** allows you to append multiple site collections to the path that you specify. For example, if you add /engineering as a wildcard inclusion off of your root site of http://contoso, then you'll be able to create multiple site collections off of http://contoso/engineering.

**An explicit inclusion** allows you to create a single site collection with the specified address. For example, if you add /finance as an explicit inclusion off of your root site of http://contoso, then you'll be able to create a single site collection with the address http://contoso/finance.

To apply managed path

- Verify that the user account that is performing this task is a member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group.
- On the the SharePoint Central Administration website, click Application Management.
- On the Application Management page, click Manage web applications.
- Click the web application for which you want to manage paths.
- The ribbon becomes active.
- In the Manage group of the ribbon, click Managed Paths.
- On the Define Managed Paths page, in the Add a New Path section, type the path to include.
- Click Check URL to confirm the path name.
- In the Type list, select either Wildcard inclusion or Explicit inclusion to identify the type of path.
  The Wildcard inclusion type includes all paths that are subordinate to the specified path. The Explicit inclusion type includes only the site that is  indicated by the specified path. Sites subordinate to the specified path are not included.
- Click Add Path.
- When you have finished adding paths, click OK.

For more details check [Define managed paths in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261845.aspx)

`A host-named site collection` can help to  address a site collection with a unique DNS name for more details [check Host Named Site Collections](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2012/03/27/what-every-sharepoint-admin-needs-to-know-about-host-named-site-collections/)

Answer (score 2):

For SharePoint Online this is not possible and you limited only to wildcard paths like `sites` and `teams` when creating new site collection.

For on premises you need to go ahead with Host Named Site Collection (HNSC).

With HNSC you can have different site urls under the same web application.

Full detailed description you can find here - [Host-named site collection architecture and deployment (SharePoint 2013)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx)